# How to check the element is displayed on the next page or not?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to check whether the Google submit button is still displayed or not on the next page. If it is not displayed then extract some text or else close the browser.

I have tried using the `WebDriverWait` element with less seconds so that I can get the result in a faster way. But it still takes 3–4 minutes to throw the exception.

```py
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("New york")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(2)
print("System in 2 seconds sleep mode.")

before_Btn_Check_time = datetime.now()
print(before_Btn_Check_time)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 0)

try:
    ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div/div[3]/center/input[1]"
        )
    ))

    sleep(1)
    print("System in 1 seconds sleep mode.")
    print("Still on the same page..!")
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("No Google Search button was found" + str(e))
```

The expected output is to get an error message in less than 10 seconds if the button is not displayed on the next page.

Comment: Do you define `driver.implicitly_wait()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yes I have used it 
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `implicitly_wait` and `WebDriverWait` can result in unexpected behavior.

You set `WebDriverWait` timeout to 0, but `driver.find_element_by_xpath` uses the `implicitly_wait` timeout. The element will be searched up to this timeout.

Actually, `presence_of_element_located()` should receive `By` as parameter, not `WebElement`. The correct use is

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div/div[3]/center/input[1]")))
```

But the same reason apply, it will search for the element internally.

As a side note, `implicitly_wait` won't effect `driver.get()`, use `driver.set_page_load_timeout()`.

Comment: I got the answer. Thank you so much